# Mysql join calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to calculate this mysql query that orders the results based on a subquery of sorts.

Table design

```js
Reports
--------
report_id
title

Voting
--------
report_id
user_id
vote_id    //This can be 1-6
```

So I am searching the reports table but want to include a percentage of vote_id's on a join.

Because the vote_id's can be different types, I need to calculate the percentage of that occurrence compared to other votes and then order by that percentage.

Example 1 - Report 1 has four votes (vote_id's 1, 1, 2, 3) so if I am searching for vote_id 1 it would come up 50%.

Example 2 - If I am searching for vote_id 3 it would come up 25%.

Comment: What is vote_id? You don't have such field in your "Table Design".

Comment: vote_id would join to another table to retrieve vote_name, vote_description. Votes can be 'interesting', 'boring', 'accurate', 'true' - ie(1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: Sorry just realized I put vote_int instead of vote_id

Comment: Edit your question and add that to your "table design", made me confused, might confuse other readers too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT vote_id,
  ( COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Voting WHERE report_id = 1) ) * 100 AS percentage
  FROM Voting WHERE report_id = 1
  GROUP BY vote_id
```

This gives you a list of all vote_id's in report 1 with their corresponding percentage.

Comment: Would this work in a join query though? As in search all reports and order by percentage vote_id 1?